# Как скрыть элементы при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать кнопку которая будет закрывать ранее открытую вкладку?

Я учу JavaScript и немного не понял почему не могу скрыть файл. Искал в гугле, но не нашел. Есть 2 кнопки, по нажатию одной появляеться `div`, по другой он должен скрыться. Почему у меня не выходит? Подскажите, пожалуйста, верный вариант.

```js
function hello() {
  console.log("ADASDASDello");

}

var btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
console.log(btn);
btn.onclick = hello;


var showModal = document.querySelector("#modal-show");

function show() {
  let modal = document.querySelector(".modal");

  modal.style.display = "block";
}

showModal.onclick = show;

var hideModal = document.querySelector("#modal-hide");

function hide() {
  let modal = document.querySelector(".modal");

  modal.style.display = "hide";
}

hideModal.onClick = hide;
```

```css
.modal {
  width: 200px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #0c0c0c;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  display: none
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Push me!</button>
<button id="modal-show">Show</button>
<button id="modal-hide">Hide</button>
<div class="modal"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код вполне рабочий, за исключеием пары моментов:

1. `hideModal.onClick = hide;`, все события в нижнем регистре, т.е. `onclick`, как на кнопке showModal
2. `modal.style.display = "hide";` - значения `hide` для css свойства `display` не существует. Для скрытия нужно использовать `none`, т.е. `modal.style.display = "none";`

Будьте внимательнее, оба случая используются у вас в коде без ошибок.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Как обычно моя невнимательность.